# How can I join two tables and keep both matched and unmatched values from the joining column?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have two tables in Power Query that look like this:

Table A

| ID | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |

Table B

| ID | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

Expected Outcome of joining tables (joining on ID column):

| ID | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |

But when I perform a full outer join in Power Query (in order to keep unmatched rows of data), I get this:

| ID | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
|  | D |
|  | E |

I get the values from Table B Col 2, but I am missing the unmatched IDs from Table B.

How can I perform this kind of join in Power Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Full Outer Join` in Power Query

[image]

---

To accomplish this task follow the steps:

1. Select some data in the first table,
2. From Data Tab --> Click on From Table/Range Under Get & Transform Data.
3. This opens the PQ Editor, and select the Close & Load To From Home Tab, and import as Only Create Connection.
4. Follow the steps 1 To 3 for the second table and import it as a connection as well.
5. Now, from Data Tab --> Get Data --> Click on Combine Queries & Select Merge.
6. On selecting the above, a new window opens which shows as below, select the id for both the tables and select the join kind as Full Outer

[image]

7. Once now the PQ Editor opens, click on Advance Editor from the Home Tab, remove anything that shows and paste the following M-Code

---

```
let
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table14, {"ID"}, Table13, {"ID"}, "Table13", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Expanded Table13" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table13", {"ID", "Col 2"}, {"ID.1", "Col 2.1"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Expanded Table13",{"Col 2.1", "Col 2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Merged Columns",{"ID", "ID.1", "Merged"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"ID"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

Note kindly change the table names as with your existing ones as well, and import the data again to excel to get the desired output you are looking for.

---

Updated M-Code:

[image]

---

```
let
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableOne"]}[Content],
    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableTwo"]}[Content],
    MergeTables = Table.NestedJoin(SourceOne, {"ID"}, SourceTwo, {"ID"}, "SourceTwo", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    Expanded = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeTables, "SourceTwo", {"ID", "Col 2"}, {"ID.1", "Col 2.1"}),
    MergedColumns = Table.CombineColumns(Expanded,{"Col 2.1", "Col 2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    ReorderedColumns = Table.ReorderColumns(MergedColumns,{"ID", "ID.1", "Merged"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(ReorderedColumns,{"ID"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

---

With the present M-Code, you need to do only three things, convert both the ranges into a table and open a blank query and paste the above M-Code by removing the existing one.

---

Comment: is there a way to do this without selecting/highlighting data as tables? I ask because I am actually merging two different results of power queries and so I will have to refresh this data frequently...

Comment: You meant to say, directly creating the joins without creating one by one connection?, if I have understood correctly then one moment I am updating the code.

Comment: one sec I will try your solution again step by step and will check if there is still an issue.

Comment: @BrendaThompson here is a working file you can download from here as well. [PQ](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ciVQ4OwOg6YnIo5hw?e=s9p95O)

Comment: hi -- I apologize, it turns out I was importing my data incorrectly. I am now able to perform a normal table merge.

Comment: @BrendaThompson Sounds Good, glad to know you have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your data is oversimplified, but why not just append the two tables and remove the rows with null in Col2?

```
let Source = Table.SelectRows(Table.Combine({TableA, TableB}), each [Col 2] <> null) in Source
```

Comment: yeah the data here is oversimplified. so it won't be as easy as just removing rows. some rows with null values in table a col b have values in col c that I need for example.